# SignalR broadcast don't hit my Mobile View in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using FireFox with [User Agent Switch](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/developers) complement to switch between my Web View and Mobile View in my MVC project.

When a click in a button is triggered, I sent to all users (broadcast) a simple alert, just testing this with [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

This little sample works fine if I'm on Web View with 2 distinct sessions, like one in Google Chrome and another in Firefox.

When I switch the User Agent to iPhone, the browser loads my Mobile View. If in another session with my Web View loaded, and click on the button to do a simple alert in broadcast (using SignalR), it doesn't work on my Mobile View, just don't appear the alert in Mobile View.

Someone has some idea ?

**SignalR Client Side code**

```
    var chat2 = $.connection.redirecionarEtapa;

    chat2.client.broadcastMessage = function (nome, mensagem) {            
         alert("teste");
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#btnConcluirContaPagar').click(function () {                              
           chat2.server.send($.cookie("login"), "Test!");                    
        });
    });
```

**SignalR Server Side code**

```
 public void Send(string nome, string mensagem)
 {
       Clients.All.broadcastMessage(nome, mensagem);            
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried [enabling logging](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging) in the client with `$.connection.hub.logging = true;` before the start() call? You should get more information on what's going on

Comment: @thepirat000 "Unfortunately" I try this right now and has no errors.